# Splitting an Ordered List into two columns

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, web-frontend

So I have been trying to split my ordered list, which contains skill names, into two columns, but the columns are not on the equal level. I tried to fix it by adding padding and margins as such, but it doesn't work.

Here's my code -

```css
.ss {
  background-color: rgba(67, 55, 76, 0.99);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #f54171, #29c450de 2100px);
  position: relative;
}

.ss::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  content: " ";
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}

.ss::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1077px;
  content: " ";
  background-image: url("../img/section_pattern01.png");
  opacity: 1;
  background-position: -80px 50px;
}

.ss_hollow-arrow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url("../img/content_hollow-arrow.png");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.ss_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 110px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

ol.gradient-list>li,
ol.gradient-list>li::before {
  box-shadow: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0.6rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 0.5rem 1.125rem rgba(75, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

ol {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  display: flexbox;
}

ol.gradient-list {
  counter-reset: gradient-counter;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1.75rem 0;
  padding-left: 25%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-top: 8%;
  width: fit-content;
  align-content: center;
}

ol.gradient-list>li {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  counter-increment: gradient-counter;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  min-height: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 3rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

ol.gradient-list>li::before {
  align-items: center;
  content: counter(gradient-counter);
  color: #1d1f20;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 25px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0.125em 0.25em;
  z-index: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+1):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(7, 207, 233, 0.534) 0%, rgba(221, 7, 96, 0.726) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+2):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0.4) 0%, rgba(253, 220, 50, 0.4) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+3):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0.6) 0%, rgba(253, 220, 50, 0.6) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+4):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0.8) 0%, rgba(28, 128, 209, 0.8) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+5):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(56, 95, 201) 0%, rgb(206, 75, 108) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+6):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(192, 45, 101, 0.8) 0%, rgba(27, 167, 155, 0.8) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+7):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0.6) 0%, rgba(253, 220, 50, 0.6) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+8):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0.4) 0%, rgba(253, 220, 50, 0.4) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+9):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0.2) 0%, rgba(253, 220, 50, 0.2) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+10):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0) 0%, rgba(253, 220, 50, 0) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li+li {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}

ol.listitem {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="softskill" class="ss">

  <div class="ss_wrapper">
    <div class="section-header">
      <div class="section-header__title  section-header__title--softskill">My Soft Skills...</div>
      <div class="section-header__subtitle">Software and technologies that I'm experienced in</div>
    </div>

    <ol class="gradient-list">

      <li>Communication Skills</li>
      <li>Time Management</li>
      <li>Critical Thinking</li>
      <li>Creative Thinking</li>
      <li>Leadership Skills</li>
      <li>Disciplined</li>
      <li>Positive Attitude</li>
      <li>Confidence</li>
      <li>Problem Solving</li>
      <li>Active Listening</li>

    </ol>

    <table>

    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

The Output -
[Contains output of given code snippet as per my website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bGuvk.png)

Sorry for the messy CSS. Please help me figure out what I have been doing wrong.

PS - I tried using js to separate it into two columns as given in other answers of similar question, but it doesn't work.

Comment: remove `margin-top: 1rem;` to have a try

Comment: remove ```margin-top: 1rem;``` from this part of CSS ```ol.gradient-list>li```

Comment: If you want to split the `li` into two columns then use CSS grid

Comment: okay, let me check if this works

Comment: Thank you both
It worked completely fine after doing this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said in the comments, you can remove the `margin-top: 1rem;` from `ol.gradient-list>li` (open snippet in full-page mode to see it properly).

```css
.ss {
  background-color: rgba(67, 55, 76, 0.99);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #f54171, #29c450de 2100px);
  position: relative;
}

.ss::before {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  content: " ";
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)));
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
}

.ss::after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 50;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1077px;
  content: " ";
  background-image: url("../img/section_pattern01.png");
  opacity: 1;
  background-position: -80px 50px;
}

.ss_hollow-arrow {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url("../img/content_hollow-arrow.png");
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  position: relative;
  top: -40px;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
}

.ss_wrapper {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 200;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 110px;
  padding-bottom: 200px;
}

ol.gradient-list>li,
ol.gradient-list>li::before {
  box-shadow: 0.25rem 0.25rem 0.6rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 0.5rem 1.125rem rgba(75, 0, 0, 0.05);
}

ol {
  columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;
  display: flexbox;
}

ol.gradient-list {
  counter-reset: gradient-counter;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 1.75rem 0;
  padding-left: 25%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-top: 8%;
  width: fit-content;
  align-content: center;
}

ol.gradient-list>li {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 0 0.5rem 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  counter-increment: gradient-counter;
  min-height: 3rem;
  padding: 1rem 1rem 1rem 3rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}

ol.gradient-list>li::before {
  align-items: center;
  content: counter(gradient-counter);
  color: #1d1f20;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 25px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding: 0.125em 0.25em;
  z-index: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+1):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(7, 207, 233, 0.534) 0%, rgba(221, 7, 96, 0.726) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+2):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0.4) 0%, rgba(253, 220, 50, 0.4) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+3):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0.6) 0%, rgba(253, 220, 50, 0.6) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+4):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0.8) 0%, rgba(28, 128, 209, 0.8) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+5):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(56, 95, 201) 0%, rgb(206, 75, 108) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+6):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(192, 45, 101, 0.8) 0%, rgba(27, 167, 155, 0.8) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+7):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0.6) 0%, rgba(253, 220, 50, 0.6) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+8):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0.4) 0%, rgba(253, 220, 50, 0.4) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+9):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0.2) 0%, rgba(253, 220, 50, 0.2) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li:nth-child(10n+10):before {
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(162, 237, 86, 0) 0%, rgba(253, 220, 50, 0) 100%);
}

ol.gradient-list>li+li {
  margin-top: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 25px;
}

ol.listitem {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section id="softskill" class="ss">

  <div class="ss_wrapper">
    <div class="section-header">
      <div class="section-header__title  section-header__title--softskill">My Soft Skills...</div>
      <div class="section-header__subtitle">Software and technologies that I'm experienced in</div>
    </div>

    <ol class="gradient-list">

      <li>Communication Skills</li>
      <li>Time Management</li>
      <li>Critical Thinking</li>
      <li>Creative Thinking</li>
      <li>Leadership Skills</li>
      <li>Disciplined</li>
      <li>Positive Attitude</li>
      <li>Confidence</li>
      <li>Problem Solving</li>
      <li>Active Listening</li>

    </ol>

    <table>

    </table>
  </div>
</section>
```

Note that your code can be improved in many ways. I would suggest posting it at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) for further feedback.

Comment: Damn, this worked perfectly!!!! N heck was I trying every other thing possible...  
Can you also guide me if I can put space, as in, empty gap between the two columns??

Comment: @ChaitanyaVishwakarma You could, for example, add `margin-right: 4rem;` to `ol.gradient-list>li`.